# Cannot start new activity in the AsyncTask

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio, android-asynctask

Here is my login activity. The loginButtonListener declares a AsyncTask variable to work on the verify info on remote MySQL

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {
    private EditText editText_email;
    private EditText editText_password;
    private Button button_login;
    private Button button_register;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker(LoginActivity.this);
    loginButtonListener();
    registerButtonListener();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}



public void loginButtonListener(){
    button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String type = "login";
            String email = editText_email.getText().toString();
            String password = editText_password.getText().toString();

            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker(LoginActivity.this);
            worker.execute(type, email, password);

        }
    });

}

}
```

Here is my backgroundwork.class

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
   AlertDialog alertDialog;
   public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
    }

// Http MySQL stuffs


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override   
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //LoginActivity.get=result;
    //delegate.processFinish(result);
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
    if(result.contains("Remote login success")){
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainpanelActivity.class); // ERROR HERE, FIRST ARGUMENT IS NOT AN ENCLOSING CLASS
        i.putExtra("email", this.email); /
        startActivity(i); 

    }

}
}
```

However, I got a "xxx is not an enclosing class error" in the onpostexecute() when I try starting a new activity (login success, jumps to another activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call the activity from following code,

```
if(result.contains("Remote login success")){
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainpanelActivity.class); //use context here
    i.putExtra("email", this.email); 
    startActivity(i); 

}
```

Comment: LoginActivity.this not working outside of activity..you must pass the context for intents.

Comment: startActivity(i) did not work, I changed to context.startActivity(i) but when it runs and finish log in , the program crashed? any suggestions? I can accept in 7 more minutes